# On possibily migrating astrophotography questions from Physics.SE to Photography.SE

Tags: discussion, scope

I opened [a question on this topic on meta.photography.se](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2293/7441) so that the proposed recipients can weight in.

Comment: Locking this so that comments and answers have to go to Photo.SE...

Comment: Did you intend to lock this and forget? It's not locked.

Comment: @ColinK It seem that locks on meta expire. I don't know what's up with that.